# How does jQuery makes the jQuery object both a function and an object property?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, object, properties

I've been wondering for a long time how jQuery can be both a function and an object property.

You can use it like a function, jQuery(...) and you can use it like a property jQuery.ajax(...)

How can you achieve a such thing in Javascript?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

functions are objects in javascript. So you can have your main function

```
var $ = function() {  alert('wat'); }
```

and then extend it

```
$.fadeTo = function() { alert('fadeto'); }
```

Comment: mhm, I see... A Javascript class doesn't not have the notion of static/dynamic methods?

Comment: @SBSTP: JavaScript doesn't have classes at all, it's a prototypical language, not a class-based one. It has constructor functions. Constructor functions create objects.

Answer (score 9):

Because in JavaScript, functions are objects that can have properties:

```
function test() { ... }

test.a = function () { ... };
test.a(); // totally valid
```

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize this. Question: In your example, can `test.a` be defined within the initial `function test() {...}` declaration, or must `test.a` be declared separately in order to be accessible outside of `test()`? In other words, is it possible to define the `a` property from within the `test(){...}` declaration such that it is still accessible from outside of `test()`? I cannot seem to find the answer anywhere else.

Answer (score 2):

I think the concept of what exactly is jQuery in terms of code concepts is quite confusing. I ran across this link, which explains the jQuery Architecture in a very simple and easy manner : http://blog.mikecouturier.com/2010/02/beginning-with-jquery-solid-foundation_22.html

So, in short, $ is an alias for a JavaScript function called 'jQuery', and methods invoked by using a dot notation  like $.trim ( ) are static methods on the 'JavaScript 'jQuery' function. Note that a function inherits from object in JavaScript, and so a function is an object in JavaScript.