# JavaScript Anonymous Method

Tags: javascript

Hi I am building a small simple JS framework for University. I am having issues with doing something like jQuery.

Currently I can call methods by `$.method()` but struggling on how they do the `$().method()` as I have looked at the source and can't seem to work out how they actually achieved it. As every time I try to adapt mine to look like theirs it does not work.

So what is the best way to achieve this.

Comment: Related/dupe: [How can jQuery behave like an object and a function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8734115/how-can-jquery-behave-like-an-object-and-a-function)

Comment: Don't assume jQuery library design is good. [It's not](https://gist.github.com/1417030). I recommend you design the framework however you want.

Comment: The right term is not, *anonymous method*. You're looking for methods in the pool of prototype, chaining.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function $() {
    return Object.create(Proto);
}

$.method = function method() { ... };
Proto.method = function method() { ... };

$.method();
$().method();
```

So you have a function with properties that are methods and your function returns an object which has methods.

Also another pro tip, `$` is a poor variable name, use something more meaningful.

Answer (score 1):

Every chainable function call works that way because every function call returns the jQuery object.

For instance,

```
var $=function(){ return $; }; 
$.foo = function(){return "foo"};

$().foo() //Outputs "foo"
```