# How can jquery $ act as an object as well as a function in javascript?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can jQuery behave like an object and a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8734115/how-can-jquery-behave-like-an-object-and-a-function)

In jquery we can use $ as a function as well as a namespace. for example both of these use-cases are valid.

1. `$("div").html("<b>Wow!</b> Such excitement...");`
2. `var trimmed = $.trim(someString);`

How can one identifier $ act as an **object** as well as a **function** at the same time?

Comment: All functions in JavaScript are objects. You can create your own function, and then attach properties to it just like you would an object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First things first: `jQuery` (or its alias `$`) is a *function*. This is very important because functions are "first-class" objects in JavaScript. And since they are objects themselves, they have the ability to be given properties and methods just as any other object. For example:

```
var f = function() {};

f.h = function(x) {
    console.log(x);
};
```

This is what allows jQuery to work its magic. In addition, through the use of inheritance, we have the potential to *chain* methods like you show in your first example. `$(selector)` returns a jQuery "interface" (technically `[object Object]`) based on the value of `selector` which, off of which, we can run methods such as `.html`, `.css`, and `.toggle` to name a few.

Answer (score 3):

It is not.

`$` is **only** a function.

It has prototype functions as well which can be used, since a function *can* have other function as a part of it (since a function is an object in and of itself).

---

You can do:

```
console.log( Object.getOwnPropertyNames($) );
```

to see all of the attached functions (and properties).

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer, can you please describe prototype function part with details?

Comment: But functions are objects in JavaScript.

Comment: It can have properties whose values are functions, or they can be strings, numbers, other objects, etc.

Comment: @Pointy I thought that was a given... but I added that as well.

Comment: @Neal well I agree it ought to be pretty obvious but in the context of this particular question it seems like it'd be good to cover all the bases :-)

Comment: @Pointy that is very true :-)