# Variables in function must be public if need change them?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

For example:

```
function foo() {

  var bar = "", obj = {};

  obj.change = function(key, val){
    // how change bar?
    return obj;
  }

  return obj;
}

foo().change("bar", "foo");
```

If `bar` will be `obj.bar` answer is `obj[key] = val;` but then `bar` will be public. I want to have ability to set `bar` in jQuery-like style, but not to make it public.

Comment: What do you mean by jQuery-like style? can you give an example?

Comment: In this example, `bar`  is a local variable in the function `foo`. The moment `foo` returns, `bar` doesn't exist anymore. `obj`, the return value of `foo` has no field named `bar`.

Comment: @SelvamPalanimalai method `change()` is example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Final code inspired by [`elclanrs`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/670396/elclanrs) [`answer`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18580225/712308), [`this`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8734157/712308) answer and [`this`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/383503/712308) answer:

```
(function(window) {
    var private = {
        name: 'John'
    };
    function foo() {
      // if without `new` foo().change() will not work :(
      // but foo.change() will
      if (!(this instanceof foo))
          return new foo();
      return this;
    }
    foo.change = function(key, val) {
      private[key] = val;
      foo.say();
      return this;
    };
    foo.say = function() {
      console.log('Hello '+ private.name);
      return this;
    }; // prototype used for foo().say() and foo().change()
    foo.prototype.change = function(key, val) {
      return foo.change(key, val);
    };
    foo.prototype.say = function() {
      return foo.say();
    };
    window.foo = foo;
})(window);

foo.say().change('name', 'Ben'); 
// => "Hello John" => "Hello Ben"
foo().change('name', 'Mike').change('name', 'Sam');
// => "Hello Mike" => "Hello Sam"
```

[**`jsfiddle.net`**](http://jsfiddle.net/1337/SNJKk/4/)

Answer (score 2):

You could encapsulate your code in an IIFE (immediately invoked function expression), and create two objects, one for `public` members, and another for `private` members. By using a closure you keep `private` private, and expose what you need.

```
var foo = (function() {

  var public = {},
      private = {
        name: 'John'
      };

  public.change = function(key, val) {
    private[key] = val;
  };

  public.say = function() {
    return 'Hello '+ private.name;
  };

  return public;
}());

console.log(foo.say()); //=> "Hello John"

foo.change('name', 'Mike');
console.log(foo.say()); //=> "Hello Mike"
```

Read about the [Revealing Module Pattern](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#revealingmodulepatternjavascript) for more info.

Comment: Few questions. Is this way common? How to make `foo()` global `F()` (for example), like `$()` in jQuery? `this` for this question is unusable?

Comment: Yes it is a common pattern, but jQuery uses a constructor and a `prototype` AFAIK. The module pattern like above is typically used for singletons. Check the [jQuery source](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js) to see how it is structured.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change variable with arbitrary name from closure scope, thouh. Need to put them in some object for reference:

```
function foo() {
  var data = {},
      obj = {};
  obj.change = function(key, val){
    if (arguments.length === 2) {
      data[key] = val;
      return obj
    } else if (arguments.length === 1) {
      return data[key];
    }
  }
  return obj;
}

foo().change("bar", "foo")
```

Answer (score 0):

currently bar is private because its within the foo function's scope. Cant be accessed from outside.
A simple solution will be to keep a private array list with all the keys.

```
function foo() {
 //private variables. Thanks to closure.
 var _privateKeys = [],
     obj = {};

 obj.change = function(key, val){
 if(arguments.length == 2)
   _privateKeys[key]=val;
 return obj;
 }

 return obj;
}

foo().change("bar", "foo");
```