# Can the dollar sign be considered a macro in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, macros

I know a dollar sign (`$`) is a replacement for `jQuery` and is used for accessing functions and variables from the jQuery object. Can this be considered the equivalent of a macro in C since it helps us not to type jQuery every time acting just like a macro in C?

Comment: With your very loose definition of a macro, any variable could be considered a macro. All variables are just stand-ins for some other value.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't call it a macro since it isn't handled in any kind of preprocessor. Instead, it's just an alias. For example, in C, you could have two variables for the same pointer:

```
int * a = malloc(sizeof(int));
int * b = a;
```

Likewise, in Javascript, you get this kind of relationship for jQuery:

```
var jQuery = ...;
var $ = jQuery;
```

They both "point" to the same object, there's no processing work done like what you would get with a macro.

Comment: So I guess they did not think about scenario when somebody used another variable named $ before switching to jquerry...

Comment: @yoyo_fun They actually did. They chose it because `$` was an uncommon variable name and they even added in [`noConflict`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/) to handle that very scenario.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for the insight. Also what type is the $ variable? is it a normal javascript object?

Comment: It's a function actually. In JavaScript though, functions are objects too. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7073647/how-does-jquery-makes-the-jquery-object-both-a-function-and-an-object-property).

Answer (score 1):

`$` is a variable that you can use in javascript.

as is `_` which some other libraries use.

There is nothing really special about it other than being a one character valid variable name.

You can redefine it yourself anywhere `$ = fooBar();`

Comment: What is the type of the $ variable? Is it an object or a function?

Comment: @yoyo_fun whatever you want. in jQuery's case it is a function.